# Как верно оформлять ссылки на сторонние ресурсы?

Tags: seo

```
<a href="https://site.ru" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer">https://site.ru</a>
```

К ссылкам на сторонние сайты добавляю атрибут `rel` c содержимым `nofollow noopener noreferrer`

На многих популярных ресурсах, вижу что ссылки на сторонние сайта имеют следующий вид

`href="/riderict/?url=https://site.ru"`

Почему именно ссылка ведет на тот же сайт, где в дальнейшем делается перенаправление?
Возможно ведь добавить к ссылке на сторонний ресурс `nofollow noopener noreferrer`, тогда робот не  переходить не индексировать не будет.

Или с перенаправлением это лучше для seo сказывается?

Answer (score 0):

По моему опыту, никакого профита особо от таких шагов не будет. Можете пользоваться `nofollow` , если хотите чуть разбавить ссылки, но добавление лишних тегов не панацея. Куча ресурсов экспериментирует с этим, но толку от этого мало.
На одном из ресурсов делали редирект через прокладку, типа предупреждаем, что при переходе на другой сайт мы уже не отвечаем за сохранность ваших данных. Тоже дельный вариант.
Но поверьте, разницы для seo почти нет, хоть так, хоть эдак.

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос